# Handlebars.js: Construct to see if an Object node includes children?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I want to add a `data-attribute` to list item based on if the object it's displaying contains a certain child node.

The child node I'm looking to check for is `source.menu.[0].menu.menu.text` (poorly structured I know)

**Ex HTML:**

```
{{#each source.menu.[0].menu}}
    <ul class='list-{{@index}}'>
        {{#each menu}}
        <li data-contains='{{source.menu.[0].menu.menu has text == 'yes'}}'>{{text}}</li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
{{/each}}
```

**Ex Object:**

```
{
    "menu":
    [
        {
            "text": "Soil",
            "menu" :[
                {
                    "text": "Clogs",
                    "menu":[
                        {"text":"Product A", "link": "/url/to/product/a"},
                        {"text":"Product B", "link": "/url/to/product/b"},
                        {"text":"Product G", "link": "/url/to/product/b"}
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "text": "Drain",
                    "menu":[
                        {"text":"Product C", "link": "/url/to/product/c"},
                        {"text":"Product D", "link": "/url/to/product/d"}
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "text": "Appliances",
                    "menu":[
                        {
                            "text": "Microwave",
                            "menu":[
                                {"text":"Product E", "link": "/url/to/product/e"},
                                {"text":"Product D", "link": "/url/to/product/d"}
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "text": "Stove",
                            "menu":[
                                {"text":"Product H", "link": "/url/to/product/e"},
                                {"text":"Product I", "link": "/url/to/product/d"}
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "text": "Surface",
            "menu" :[
                {
                    "text": "Wood",
                    "menu" :[
                        {"text":"Product A", "link": "/url/to/product/a"},
                        {"text":"Product B", "link": "/url/to/product/b"}
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "text": "Granite",
                    "menu" :[
                        {"text":"Product C", "link": "/url/to/product/c"},
                        {"text":"Product D", "link": "/url/to/product/d"}
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "text": "Appliances",
                    "menu" :[
                        {
                            "text": "Microwave",
                            "menu" :[
                                {"text":"Product E", "link": "/url/to/product/e"},
                                {"text":"Product D", "link": "/url/to/product/d"}
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "text": "Stove",
                            "menu" :[
                                {"text":"Product E", "link": "/url/to/product/e"},
                                {"text":"Product D", "link": "/url/to/product/d"}
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Added the object for clarity.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give us an example context object as I think you may also have some other issues with your template

Comment: Addded the object! I'm using the source.menu.[0] has as I have two seperate handlebars templates and am rendering them one at a time (Soil and Surface)

Comment: So you're trying to verify that the sub menu, eg `"menu":[
                                {"text":"Product E", "link": "/url/to/product/e"}
                            ]` has a child with prop text?

Comment: Just trying to verify that the Object exists, menu Stove and Microwave. I need to link that LI in that UL to another li in a different UL... maybe grab that index? if possible.

Comment: That was a little unclear, that ul links to a second list, which if that object has children, I need it to link to a third list. I'm grabbing the index of that second list (that contains the child node) to link to the third list. Think IPhone tab menu where you click a list item and the page swipes left-to-right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I was looking at this the wrong way.

Because of the generic data structure, I can just check to see if the object contains `{{link}}` and if it doesn't, then I know there's children.

```
{{#each source.menu.[0].menu}}
    <ul class='list-{{@index}}'>
        {{#each menu}}
        <li data-list-index='{{@index}}' data-product-url='{{link}}'>{{text}}</li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
{{/each}}


function checkForProductUrl(element) {
    if (element.data('product-url') === '' || null) {
        // Code to continue to next list
        var $activeListIndex;

        $('.list-second-level').animate({ 
            left: $listWidth}, 500);

        activeListIndex = element.data('list-index');
        $('#mask .list-third-level ul.list-' + activeListIndex).show();
        currentListLevel = 3;
    } else {
        displayProductInformation(element.data('product-url'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Handlebars is logic less by design, so you could do something like this:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('exists', function(text) {
    return !!text
})
```

Which could be used like this (including adjustments above):

```
{{#each source.menu.[0].menu}}
    <ul class='list-{{@index}}'>
        {{#each menu}}
            <li data-contains='{{exists ../text}}'>{{text}}</li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Added the object to the question! I also explained why I'm using the hash in my prior comment! Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: Ah I get you now. Handlebars is logic less, unlike angular, so you can't just add some javascript into the html (as you probably have found out). So you'll have to abstract it out into a helper. Does that make sense?

Comment: @ChristopherMarshall I just commented there.

Comment: Question for you: `source.menu.[0].menu.menu[i].text` is effectively just `text` (the same text that comes up as the text in the li. That's what you want to check exists right? Your comments seem to indicate something different?

Comment: Basically, yes. I just need to see if that Object exists in that "third" node.

Comment: Right.. Updated, but on my phone so couldn't test, but that should be fine if I remember correctly

Comment: That shows True for all of the nodes in the second level, Clogs, Drains, Appliances, when it should only show true for appliances.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of your issue you're trying to check if a property exists in the scope up. We can actually do this without a helper using the pathing system baked into Handlebars.

Try this template and let me know if that is whats desired (otherwise can you give expected output) http://jsbin.com/aluhupI/2/edit

```
{{#each menu}}
    <ul class='list-{{@index}}'>
        {{#each menu}}
            <li data-contains='{{#if ../text}}true{{else}}false{{/if}}'>{{text}}</li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
{{/each}}
```